# Add column to data frame containing the first value only of other rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame (df):

```
RT1     RT2    RT3 
0.777   0.323  1.654      
NA      NA     NA      
0.766   0.804  NA      
0.887   NA     NA      
NA      NA     1.271   
0.832   NA     NA
```

I would like to add a column 'RTfirst' that provides the first integer (non-NA) value only in each row, so that it looks like:

```
RT1     RT2    RT3     RTFirst
0.777   0.323  1.654   0.777
NA      NA     NA      NA
0.766   0.804  NA      0.766
0.887   NA     NA      0.887
NA      NA     1.271   1.271
0.832   NA     NA      0.832
```

I have tried calculating mean RTs for each row using the 'apply' function, and then using 'if then' statements based on a count of the number of NAs in each row (e.g., if CountNA < = 1, etc.), but I feel like that is probably over-complicating it.

Is there a more obvious solution?

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked before.  `max.col()` works, `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "first"))]` gives you the new column values

Comment: Check out `coalesce` in dplyr.

Comment: I'm fond of `Reduce(dplyr::coalesce, df)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `purrr` package:

```
df <- data.frame(
  RT1 = c(0.777, NA, 0.766, 0.887, NA, 0.832),
  RT2 = c(0.323, NA, 0.804, NA, NA, NA),
  RT3 = c(1.654, NA, NA, NA, 1.271, NA)
)
library(purrr)
m <- as.matrix(df)
RTFirst <- apply(X = m, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) detect(row, function(x) !is.na(x)))
RTFirst <- vapply(RTFirst, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x), numeric(1))
cbind(df, RTFirst)
```

(Edit: I had not checked Rich's solution in his comment before. His is actually more elegant and does not require third-party packages).

Comment: Only `detect` is from purrr, but you might as well translate the whole thing: `df %>% transpose() %>% map_dbl(~detect(.x, ~!is.na(.x)) %||% NA)`